# Camera2 api is not working in Samsung galaxy j7

Tags: android, android-camera2, samsung-galaxy

I am using [this Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) code to take a picture, It's working in all phones but when I tested in Samsung galaxy j7 pro it's not taking the picture and not throwing any kind of exception.

When I use [this sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video) to record the video it's only recording the voice, not visuals. Anyone know why?

**EDIT**
it has android 8.1.0

Details provided from [Camera2 api probe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airbeat.device.inspector)

```
Camera ID: 1
Camera Facing: Front
SupportLevel:LIMITED
Hardware Support Level:LIMITED
Manual exposure:1
Auto exposure:1
Auto exposure, always flash:0
Auto exposure, auto flash:0
Auto exposure, auto flash, red eye reduction:0
AE Lock:1
Manual focus:1
Auto focus:0
Auto focus macro:0
Auto focus continuous picture:0
Auto focus continuous video:0
Auto focus EDOF:0
White balance off:1
Automatic white balance:1
WB: cloudy day:1
WB: day:1
WB: fluorescent:1
WB: incandescent:1
WB: shade:0
WB: twilight:0
WB: warm fluorescent:0
AWB Lock:1
RawCapture:1
BurstCapture:1
previewSize: 4128 * 3096 (4:3)
previewSize: 4128 * 2322 (16:9)
previewSize: 3264 * 2448 (4:3)
previewSize: 3264 * 1836 (16:9)
previewSize: 3088 * 3088 (1:1)
previewSize: 2048 * 1536 (4:3)
previewSize: 2048 * 1152 (16:9)
previewSize: 1920 * 1080 (16:9)
previewSize: 1440 * 1080 (4:3)
previewSize: 1280 * 720 (16:9)
previewSize: 960 * 720 (4:3)
previewSize: 720 * 480 (3:2)
previewSize: 640 * 480 (4:3)
previewSize: 352 * 288 (11:9)
previewSize: 320 * 240 (4:3)
previewSize: 256 * 144 (16:9)
previewSize: 176 * 144 (11:9)
photoSize: 4128 * 3096 (4:3)
photoSize: 4128 * 2322 (16:9)
photoSize: 3264 * 2448 (4:3)
photoSize: 3264 * 1836 (16:9)
photoSize: 3088 * 3088 (1:1)
photoSize: 2048 * 1536 (4:3)
photoSize: 2048 * 1152 (16:9)
photoSize: 1920 * 1080 (16:9)
photoSize: 1440 * 1080 (4:3)
photoSize: 1280 * 720 (16:9)
photoSize: 960 * 720 (4:3)
photoSize: 720 * 480 (3:2)
photoSize: 640 * 480 (4:3)
photoSize: 352 * 288 (11:9)
photoSize: 320 * 240 (4:3)
photoSize: 256 * 144 (16:9)
photoSize: 176 * 144 (11:9)
videoSize: 4128 * 3096 (4:3)
videoSize: 4128 * 2322 (16:9)
videoSize: 3264 * 2448 (4:3)
videoSize: 3264 * 1836 (16:9)
videoSize: 3088 * 3088 (1:1)
videoSize: 2048 * 1536 (4:3)
videoSize: 2048 * 1152 (16:9)
videoSize: 1920 * 1080 (16:9)
videoSize: 1440 * 1080 (4:3)
videoSize: 1280 * 720 (16:9)
videoSize: 960 * 720 (4:3)
videoSize: 720 * 480 (3:2)
videoSize: 640 * 480 (4:3)
videoSize: 352 * 288 (11:9)
videoSize: 320 * 240 (4:3)
videoSize: 256 * 144 (16:9)
videoSize: 176 * 144 (11:9)
```

it's saying capture is not available

```
RawCapture:1
BurstCapture:1
```

so how I can capture the images and videos? any idea

Comment: could you provide more information , the os version of the working phones and the os version of the j7 ?

Comment: it's 8.1.0 Oreo

Comment: what about the other ?

Comment: other devices are from lollipop to  pie it's working fine I have testes in galaxy s8 plus, galaxy 7 working moto g5s plus, and so many devices working fine but not working in j7 pro

Comment: please check this link to learn more about camera2 api compatibility:https://www.thecustomdroid.com/check-camera2-api-support-android/

Comment: Hi I have checked the link and tested in the device and found capture is in available in that device how do you know how can I capture the video and images in this device?